# java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://[IP:8888]/oozie/versions

Tags: java, oozie, cloudera-cdh

Hi i am following the below link
http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.1/DG_JMSNotifications.html

snippet

```
 OozieClient oc = new OozieClient("http://IP:8888/oozie");
 JMSConnectionInfo jmsInfo = oc.getJMSConnectionInfo();
 Properties jndiProperties = jmsInfo.getJNDIProperties();
 Context jndiContext = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);
```

however as per the sample code given as above when trying to see the debug information     for getting JMSConnectionInfo it says

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://[ip:8888]/oozie/versions
```

is it some configuration with oozie-4.0.0-cdh5.1.0 (i m using). One more info i am running the above code with separate jvm on eclipse and oozie is configured on some other machine.

I found the link http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/oozie/WebServicesAPI.html

```
this says 

The Oozie Web Services API is a HTTP REST JSON API.

All responses are in UTF-8 .

Assuming Oozie is runing at OOZIE_URL , the following web services end points are supported:

/versions
/v1/admin
/v1/job
/v1/jobs
```

in my case /versions are not supported so this is the reason. however i am not sure how i 
can make my oozieserver to support /versions. please help

Comment: updated the port information above that i was using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The port that i was using was wrong it should be 11000 instead. Due to this the oozieclient was not able to establish HTTPConnection to oozie server to get the Rest call. I am adding this as might be this is useful for some other person.